# Need to add a video on my top-wrapper, please teach me how to style css

Tags: html, css

As I tried to add a video on my top-wrapper previously.
(Thank you so much for those who leave me some comments.)
However, I still cannot solve the problem.

Well, I could upload a video, but still cannot style properly.
After I uploaded a video like  in top-wrapper, then very struggling to style....

please teach me how to code css so that i can place a video in my top-wrapper,,,

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN";
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  width: 110%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-wrapper {
padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
text-align: center;
background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}

.top-wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-wrapper p {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(34, 49, 52, 0.9);
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TakashiKaida</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header-left">
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
          <a href="file:///Users/takashikaida/Documents/Takashi%20Kaida%20Personal/index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="about">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="blog">Blog</a>
          <a href="#" class="cv">CV</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="top-wrapper">
      <div class="video" src="video3344.mov" autoplay loop muted type="video/mp4"></video>
        <div class="container">
         <h1>HELLO, IT'S ME.</h1>
         <h1>I AM TAKASHI</h1>
         <p><br><br>Marketing Analyst/Assistant</p>
         <p>Co-Founder and CEO of <a href="file:///Users/takashikaida/Desktop/Flow%20Full%20Screen%20Type/index.html" target="_blank"> <strong>FLOW</strong></a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the description of Mozilla with an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 0):

In your code add the absolute positioning for container to overlay the content. Second thing add the transparent background color `:before` for `top-wrapper` class. And also I adjusted the padding based on header height.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN";
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mt-50 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    width: 110%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.top-wrapper:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.top-wrapper {
    padding: 65px 0 0px 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.top-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 75px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-wrapper p {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(34, 49, 52, 0.9);
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-left">
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
            <a href="file:///Users/takashikaida/Documents/Takashi%20Kaida%20Personal/index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="about">About</a>
            <a href="#" class="blog">Blog</a>
            <a href="#" class="cv">CV</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="top-wrapper">
    <video autoplay loop width="100%">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> Your browser does not support the video tag. We suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>HELLO, IT'S ME.</h1>
        <h1>I AM TAKASHI</h1>
        <p class="mt-50">Marketing Analyst/Assistant</p>
        <p>Co-Founder and CEO of
            <a href="file:///Users/takashikaida/Desktop/Flow%20Full%20Screen%20Type/index.html" target="_blank"> <strong>FLOW</strong></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```